# Backing up website that uses amazon ec2 and RDS as database

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-rds

Hello I'm currently using Amazon ec2 instance to run a wordpress website 
OS is amazon linux AMI and I'm using RDS as my database

I need to back up my website without downtime is that possible? RDS has already automated backup set everyday for a week.

How do I backup my ec2 instance without downtime?

Answer (score 0):

I would arrange some sort of backup server and use something `rdiff-backup` to backup on a file level. Then also set up daily local dumps with `mysqldump`. Having file level backups allows for easy recovery of the most prevalent of errors: human error.

You could achieve the same with a separate volume, but then you could be completely wiped out when Amazon has a problem, or [somebody gains access to your account](https://threatpost.com/hacker-puts-hosting-service-code-spaces-out-of-business/106761/).

BTW, do not have the PHP code writable to the webserver. Have them be owned by a separate user (including the docroot dir itself!) and use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/). Then restrict PHP with an open base dir to its docroot. And, put a HTTP password on `wp-login.php` and `/wp-admin` (though that is harder, because some assets are loaded from there).

See the recent [Linux Mint hack](http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-mint-website-hack-a-timeline-of-events-500719.shtml).

Comment: I'm really new to Amazon is there another way that is much easier?